# How to make a table in phpword?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpword

Bellow are my code, i get four column from these, but the result shows every one data will loop in four time in one column then it appear again in new column with the same data.

```
    <?php
    $tampil_data = $this->in_elektronik_model->tampil_data(); //load data
    foreach ($tampil_data as $tampildata) { 
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            $table->addRow(500); //make new row
            for ($j = 0; $j < 4; $j++) {
                $table->addCell(2000)->addText(htmlspecialchars($tampildata->elektronik_nama)); //content of table
            }
        }
    }
```

model

```
function tampil_data() {
    $this->db->where('elektronik_status_aktif', 0);
    $tampil = $this->db->get('in_elektronik');
    if ($tampil->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $tampil->result();
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

How to make table with four column, where the content of table will appear from right column to left and appear just one data in one time, after four column are full, it makes new row?

Comment: you can also use html with php

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this code. This is the way i have done table in view page

```
 <table border="1">
     <tr role="row">
   <th  width="5%">Featured Id</th>                                   
    </tr>
    <?php
     if(!empty($results))
       {

            foreach ($results as $row) {
             ?><tr>  
    <td class=" "><?php echo $row->fet_id; ?></td>  

        </tr>  

              <?php }}
?>                                         
     </table>
```

Comment: I want to export data in ms word, so it will not detect css class.

Comment: css class is not needed